# Filter rows based on a pair of conditions in Elasticsearch in Django

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I'm working on a QA (survey) application. I have implemented Elastic Search in the application. I want to filter users based on their answers.
Suppose, there are questions:

1. Do you have a passport? Yes/No
2. Do you have a driving license? Yes/No

**Now I want to fetch those users who answered `Yes` to both questions.**

My answer document looks like this.

```
@registry.register_document
class AnswerDocument(Document):

    user = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'name': fields.TextField(),
    })
    question = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'name': fields.TextField(),
        'description': fields.TextField(),
    })

    class Index:
        name = 'answers'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0,
        }

    class Django:
        model = Answer
        fields = [
            'id',
            'yes_no_ans',
        ]
```

I have built a query expression but it's not working as expected.

```
expression = (Q('bool', should=[
                         Q('match', question__name='passport'),
                         Q('match', yes_no_ans='yes'),
                     ], minimum_should_match=2)
                )
                & 
                (Q('bool',
                      should=[
                             Q('match', question__name='driving license'),
                             Q('match', yes_no_ans='yes'),
                     ],
                     minimum_should_match=2))

response = AnswerDocument.search().query(expression).execute()
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: What is failing ? What error do you have ?

Comment: @Paulo no error actually. It just returns an empty list.

Comment: Could you show us a typical documents